# Which dynamic libraries on OS X can be taken for granted?

Tags: c++, c, macos, dynamic-linking, static-linking

If I want to make an OS X program as self-contained as possible to ease installation, what dynamic libraries can I expect everyone or most people to have? If I know that, I won't have to compile static libraries for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions listed in [Single UNIX Specification V3](http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification/) are available.

Obviously, all Cocoa frameworks are available as well. The exact contents depend on OS version.

Comment: How would you know the exact contents if you know the version?

Comment: You just tell Xcode which version you target and it will provide you with relevant frameworks. They are put is separate directories under /Developer main folder.